# Как открыть гиперссылку в Excel?

Tags: excel, url, internet-explorer

Если по умолчанию не установлен Internet Explorer, то не хочет открывать ссылку. Выводит ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю просто манипуляциями с VBA тут не обойтись. Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант решения проблемы. Проверьте наличие в реестре ключа `ForceShellExecute` по следующему пути:

*Для 32-разрядной версии Microsoft Office на 64-разрядной версии Windows*

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet\

*Для 32-разрядной версии Microsoft Office на 32-разрядной версии Windows*

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet

*Для 64-разрядной версии Office на 64-разрядной версии Windows*

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet

Создайте раздел, если он отсутствует. Добавьте ключ `ForceShellExecute` (DWORD, значение - 1).

Подробнее смотрите в [базе знаний Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/218153).